# from one json information another json link

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, decode

Hey i have problem i need from one json get information to another json link.
I need get all(maxResults) **videoId** from this link below

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCynfZM0Edr9cA4pDymb2rEA&maxResults=20&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk
```

to this link below in this area [NEED HERE videoId with , each]

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?id=[NEED HERE videoId with , each]&part=statistics&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk
```

All code

```
<?php
$videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCynfZM0Edr9cA4pDymb2rEA&maxResults=20&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk'));
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?id=[NEED HERE IDS]&part=statistics&key='.$API.'';
$videoViews = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    foreach($videoList->items as $item){
    //Shows embed videos from channels
        if(isset($item->id->videoId)){
            echo '<div class="video">           
                    <iframe width="280" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <h5>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h5>
                </div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

i need look like this 3 videoId added but from first json information

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?id=w_TLR7K_g98,H5_LI7caH1M,ishpS2v9uvo&part=statistics&key='.$API.'
```

Comment: So, what is the problem that you encounter?

Comment: From first link i get videoId's and i need add automaticly to second $url to get videoId statistic information. now i get only videoId, but i don't want add it manuali, i need to do automatic like
foreach ($videoList->items as $items) {
   if(isset($items->id->videoId)){
    echo ''.$items->id->videoId.',';
   }
  }
but in https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?id=[NEED HERE videoId with , each]&part=statistics&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk
sorry for English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all the items, and put the video IDs into an array. Then use `implode()` to combine them into a comma-separated string.

```
$videoIDs = array();
foreach ($videoList->items as $item) {
    if(isset($item->id->videoId)){
        $videoIDs[] = $item->id->videoId;
    }
}
$videosString = implode(",", $videoIDs);
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?id=' . $videosString . '&part=statistics&key='.$API;
```

In return for this code, can you please tell me why you put `.''` at the end of the `$url` assignment? I see this frequently and I never understand why people do it.

Comment: I was going to congratulate you a couple days ago for hitting 400K, then I blinked, and you are already 402K!  Quite the snowball.